# Two types of movement within singular update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry about the title I wasn't sure how to word this.

I'm working on a small project for one of my university classes. In our input section we are supposed to be able to have the sprite constantly move while a movement key is held down. On top of this, we are supposed to be able to have the sprite move only a set distance if both the shift key and one of the movement keys is held down, meaning the player would have to release the keys and press the movement key again. Within my script I'm unsure how to have this single movement happen without it then moving again afterwords.

I have this for the constant movement

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
     tf.position += (Vector3.up * speed);
}
     else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
     tf.position += (Vector3.left * speed);
}
     else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
{
     tf.position += (Vector3.down * speed);
}
     else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
     tf.position += (Vector3.right * speed);
}
```

And my attempt for the "moving a set distance" was this:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
{
     tf.position += Vector3.up;
}
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
{
     tf.position += Vector3.left;
}
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
{
     tf.position += Vector3.down;
}
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
{
     tf.position += Vector3.right;
}
```

I know that the movement can be handled in better ways but I'm curious how I can have both of these exist without the first set of code still going while they're in my update function.

Comment: Use a flag to keep current moving method. And use **Input.GetKeyUp** to rest the flag.

Comment: @siusiulala Much easier than I expected that to be. Never thought to try using a flag like "shiftPressed" or something. I appreciate that!

Comment: @siusiulala I'm running into another error actually. My GetKeyUp doesn't seem to be registering and is then locking my movement to the single teleporting kind of movement.

Comment: It was misplaced, apologies, thanks again :)

Comment: GJ ! wish you get a high score

Comment: @siusiulala I will come back and let you know on Monday when it's graded! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sugest to simply wrap the blocks in `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LefyShift)`

```
if(!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
         tf.position += (Vector3.up * speed);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
         tf.position += (Vector3.left * speed);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
         tf.position += (Vector3.down * speed);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
         tf.position += (Vector3.right * speed);
    }
}
else
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
         tf.position += Vector3.up;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
         tf.position += Vector3.left;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
         tf.position += Vector3.down;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
         tf.position += Vector3.right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh this makes a lot of sense. Thank you for this.